# Construct regular expression for given language

Tags: regular-languages, regular-expressions

How to construct regular expression for language L={a,b,c} which contain all words starts with bab and ends with babc?

Comment: Separately for *start* and *end*, with due care in combining both.

Comment: No separately.....with due care in combining both.....and with respect overlap bab with babc (here I have a problem)

Answer (score 0):

RE-(bab)star[a+b+c]star(babc)star..well you just need to care about the starting symbols and the ending symbols. And that's it. Refer to the arithmetic rules of regular expressions.

Comment: Yes, thank you Satyam Bhardwaj, I write answer like this, but prof didn't admit....He comented about overlap bab with babc....So I need help....